Visual Studio 2022 (C++) - Intellisense Not Finding Include Files
Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.10.2
Visual C++ 2022
Visual Studio IntelliCode 2.2
I have a VS2022 solution that uses an #include file from a folder outside. The file is not directly included in the project file. However, I have the #include search path set in the project properties, and the project compiles successfully.
But Intellisense and the real-time error detection cannot find the file. So my source code is littered with the red squiggles indicating syntax errors wherever anything defined in the #include file is referenced.
cannot open source file
I have tried all the standard advice (remove the .vs folder, remove the .db files, restart VS2022 and reload) and the in-line errors still persist, even though the project itself compiles correctly.
If I try to "Go to Document" on the #include file, I get an error dialog.
Error dialog
So it seems there is a disconnect between the #include search path that Intellisense is using and the one the compiler is using.
Any advice? Thanks.
=========================
I believe I have found the problem. My solution had two projects, one that build the static .lib, and a second (Utility project) with only additional header files and no output. Intellisense handled the main project OK, but failed on the Utility project.
So it appears the solution is to combine all the files into a single project.

Did you set your include path in the project properties to include the path that that header lives?

Yes, I set the path. If I hadn't, the project wouldn't compile.

Hi @JamesHulsey, which property did you set in the project properties  to include the path? Is it Additional Include Directories?


I have the #include search path set in the project properties,

Did you set Additional Include Directories in the project properties?
If no, please  add ....\SomeOtherDir to the Additional Include Directories.
C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories

Or you can use a relative path:
For example(The file test.h is from a folder outside.)
ENV:
Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.10.3/Visual C++ 2022

The IntelliSense works fine in both of above ways based on my testing. If they don't help, please try to reset your settings then restart your visual studio to reload your project to see if the issue persists.
Hope it can help you.
